# Comparing two large lists and fetching the matched results

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I tried looking for this one a lot but could not find appropriate solution. I have two large lists of string having 1.5 Million records in each. Both these lists are passed in a SQL Query inside where clause for different columns.
For Ex: `Select * from TBL1 where FOO IN (Col1_List) and BAR IN (Col2_list);`

Due to some `lambda` limitation of not supporting more than 16K values inside an `IN Clause` in SQL, I want to pass limited values for processing each time, consider below example:

```
Col1_list = ['1_a_title','2_title','3_b_title','4_c_title','5_title']  #  and so on ..
Col2_list = ['1_a','2','3_b','4_c','5']  # and so on..
```

As you can see, `Col1_list` contains some extra characters for each value( say `_title`) compared to `Col2_list`. Both lists begins with an integer and these integers ***may*** have some other characters attached (like in case of **`1_a, 3_b`**).

Objective: I want to pass 16K Values inside the `IN` Clause, so its necessary that the integer part `Col1_list` and `Col2_list` must match to produce proper sql results. I tried the below code:

**Approach 1:** - Looping over `Col2_list` and matching it to create a new list of matched records:

```
for i in range(0, len(Col2_list), 16000):
    chunk = Col2_list[i:i + 16000]
    new_kl = []
    for val_to_check in chunk:
      print(val_to_check)
      new_kl.append([item1 for item1 in Col1_list if val_to_check.split('_')[0] == item1.split('_')[0]])
      print(val_to_check + " - " + str(new_kl))
    <Do Processing for obtained 16K values>
```

**Approach 2:** Tried the same with For comprehension

```
for i in range(0, len(Col2_list), 16000):
    chunk = Col2_list[i:i + 16000]
    matched_list = [item for x in chunk for item in Col1_list if item.split('_')[0] == x.split('_')[0]]
    <Do Processing for obtained 16K values>
```

Both these approach works terribly slow. Could any one please guide me how can do it in a quicker way.

**Note:** Please do not take platform into consideration for now, i am fine with running the script on EC2 instance if required, but still need the solution for above problem.

Comment: I haven't done any sort of analysis but here are a few other ways of getting the intersection of two lists https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/

Comment: Are the values that make up those lists already in the database somewhere.  E.g. could you use a subselect to pick up those values in the query and do the matching/filtering in the DB itself.  Doing that kind of stuff in the DB is almost always going to be faster than doing it in Python.

Comment: @AnthonyOteri: Alright, I guess i can try that out, Thanks.. But what if that does not work out either (due to business logic constraint <for now>) . Is there any other solution/approach for the above problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's a Lambda limitation? It sounds like a database limitation. Have you considered connecting a more appropriate data processing tool connected to your database?

Comment: @RenatoByrro, Yes because i get an error as : { "error": "body size is too long" }. As per the given link, it mentions that its a lambda limitation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298060/aws-lambda-response-error/46298912

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion from @AnthonyOteri, I carried out the processing mostly on Database side and it worked fine and in a lot less time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already solved this using the database, but you could also considerably speed this up in Python using more appropriate data structures.

Basically, you are comparing each value in Col2 to each value in Col1 to see whether they have the same first element. Instead, you could just group the elements in Col1 by their first element, store those in a dictionary, and then get the values corresponding to the first element of the value from Col2 from that dict.

```
import collections
col1_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item1 in col1_list:
    col1_dict[item1.split('_')[0]].append(item1)

for i in range(0, len(col2_list), 16000):
    matched_list = [item for val_to_check in col2_list[i:i + 16000]
                         for item in col1_dict[val_to_check.split('_')[0]]]
    # more processing
```

This will reduce the complexity from O(#col1 x #col2) to O(#col1 + #col2). (The list comprehension still has two `for` loops, but since each item from Col1 will be in exactly one "bucket", the inner loops have a *combined* running time of #Col1 iterations only.)